# Add values from same date

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, sum

I just got started learning PHP so if there's already an answer to this question, please point me to it as I wasn't able to find one.

I have a mysqli database with 2 entries: `date_added` & `menu_price`. The user inputs (through a webpage interface) the `menu_price` (double) while the date is automatically set in this format: `Y-m-d`. Note that multiple entries for `menu_price` can be set for the same date.

My question: I'm trying to pull out a daily report which should add all prices for every day and only display the date once.

Example: let's say I had two entries for `2015-04-10`: 10 & 20 and I had 3 entries for `2015-04-11`: 10, 20 & 30. So my report for `2015-04-10` should say `30` and for `2015-04-11` should say `60`.

I managed to extract unique date entries (I'm not sure it's useful or not) the way described below but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
// Extract unique date entries
$newDate = "SELECT DISTINCT (date_added) AS date_added
            FROM main
            ORDER BY date_added DESC";

$dateResult = $conn->query($newDate);

// Create an array with unique dates
$results = array();
while ($dateArray = $dateResult->fetch_assoc())
{
    $results[] = $dateArray["date_added"];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires aggregate functions. Use [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and `GROUP BY` in your query:

```
$newDate = "SELECT date_added,
                SUM(menu_price )
            FROM main
            GROUP BY date_added
            ORDER BY date_added DESC";
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about these aggregate functions. It works perfectly :)