# Sum Up All Values Of Same Date

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to sum up All the  `amount` entries which is on same date by using the product id.

Image of the database:

[image: DATABASE]

I want to show result in such that way using php and mysql.

[image: Required]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add values from same date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579118/add-values-from-same-date)

Comment: @Jakob that was not working for me , ! will you help me out ?

Comment: just get your data for each date and product and the transform your data in application layer (through php)

Comment: AoA .. there is no other solution to avoid manually  for each date ? @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: Not manually you need to build this logic using your application code to show the data date wise

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid will you guve a simple exampl of  that, i'll be very thankful to you...

Comment: @BĩğrăyŇăwăb we're not here to write the code for you. We're more than glad to take a look at your efforts and direct in in the right direction.

Comment: @AdamA i agree with you , i'm not saying to write a code for my problem, as I'm newbiee it would be very helpful if simple example of that thorugh which i can understand it in a better way and develop my own logic according to my requirements ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. The database table has been named `tborderdetail`:

```
/* I get data using json object (for convenience): */
    $arr = [];
    $s = "SELECT product_name, SUM(amount) AS amount, DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d %b %Y') AS order_date FROM tborderdetail GROUP BY product_name, DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d %b %Y') ORDER BY order_date DESC";
    $q1 = mysqli_query($con,$s); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)){$arr[] = $row;} 
    $str = json_encode($arr);
    $data = json_decode($str);

    /* Populate three arrays that will be used to create the required table */
    $arr_dates = [];
    $arr_products = [];
    $arr_date_product_amount = [];

    foreach($data as $v){ 
    if(!in_array($v->order_date, $arr_dates)){ $arr_dates[] = $v->order_date; }
    if(!in_array($v->product_name, $arr_products)){ $arr_products[] = $v->product_name;}
    $dpv = str_replace(' ','',$v->product_name.$v->order_date);
    $arr_date_product_amount[$dpv] = $v->amount;}

    /* Start outputting the table and the top row */
    echo '<table><tr><td>Products</td>'; 
    foreach($arr_dates as $dt){ echo '<td>Sale on '.$dt.'</td>'; } 
    echo '</tr>';

    /* Output the other rows of the table: */
    foreach($arr_products as $pt){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$pt; 
    foreach($arr_dates as $dt){
    $dpv = str_replace(' ','',$pt.$dt);
    /* Ensure no errors due to missing values */
    echo '<td>'; if(array_key_exists($dpv,$arr_date_product_amount)){echo $arr_date_product_amount[$dpv];}
    echo '</td>';}
    echo '</tr>';}
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I really appeariate your effort but this code doesn't display any reuslt ! r 2ndly i would like to ask you that is loop is better way for that or ana array ?

Comment: OK, but what do you get when you run `SELECT product_name, amount, DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d %b %Y') AS order_date FROM sales GROUP BY product_name, DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d %b %Y') ORDER BY order_date desc` in phpmyadmin SQL?

Comment: it will show the result of only first first order of each product :(

Comment: Thanks, then what do you get when you run `SELECT product_name, amount, order_date FROM sales GROUP BY product_name, order_date ORDER BY order_date desc` in phpmyadmin (i.e. without formatting the order_date)?

Comment: all the orders in  date and time descending order.

Comment: That's good. I think we will get there. What data types do you have for the three columns in the table: `order_date`, `amount` and `product_name`.

Comment: `order_date` = datetime
`amount` = float
`product_name` = varchar(255)

Comment: The data types are OK. What do you get when you run `SELECT product_name, amount, DATE(order_date) AS order_date FROM sales GROUP BY product_name, DATE(order_date) ORDER BY DATE(order_date) desc` in phpmyadmin?

Comment: it will show the same result  as earlier only first first order of each product :(

Comment: `SELECT product_name, SUM(amount) AS amount, DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d %b %Y') AS order_date FROM tborderdetail GROUP BY product_name, DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d %b %Y') ORDER BY order_date DESC`

i find this one is working....

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have said `SUM(amount)  AS amount`.  I have also found that `DATE()` could be smarter here than `DATE_FORMAT()`.  I am going to change my answer, please try it out after the change.

Comment: I have made the changes to the answer. Is it now producing the table properly?

Comment: nope, your updated  query doesn't work, it will display the order in the simply desccending order only.

Comment: Possible MySQL version issues. I have changed the answer to use the query that worked for you. I hope you can now get the output table.